# Excel formula: If current time is later then

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Since i spent some time trying to find the answer to this question I decided to pass the knowledge along to save other people some time.

If the current time is later than the set time, then TRUE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this to set up an alert if orders aren't finished after 3 o'clock:

```
=VALUE(TIME(15;0;0))<VALUE(NOW())-TRUNC(VALUE(NOW()))
```

What it does is check the numerical value for (in this case) 3 oclock in the afternoon and the numerical value of the current time and checks if it is later or not.

I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

This will work if your set time has a date attached to it as well. If not, you will need to modify the `NOW()` equation to just look at the time stamp. 
Replace the value of 'X' in the above equation with the cell reference of your "Set" time.

```
=IF(NOW()> X, "TRUE", "FALSE")
```

You can change the T/F values above inside the quotations to show whatever you like (like change false to blank maybe?).

If T/F are the only outputs you will need, this can be simplified to

```
=NOW()>X
```

Excel will evaluate the expression and return True or False.

Comment: If the input is just a time stamp  [NOW()  - INT(NOW())] > X will suffice.